# Testing with dependencies from other gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, spree-auth-devise

I want to add functionality to the default User model from the [`solidus_auth_devise`](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus_auth_devise) gem and I want to write a test for it in Rspec. However, when I try to instantiate a model with `Spree::User.new`, I would get `uninitialized constant Spree` What do I have to `require` to link in the Model from the gem?